# Why <!DOCTYPE html> is included in Basic tag category?

Tags: html

I have read other answers posted here why  not a html tag. If you see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_byfunc.asp it is showing it in Basic List although in their description is written that it is not HTML tag. My question is, why it is included as inside basic tags? is there any specific reason?

Comment: W3Schools never said those were basic *tags*. The section is called "Basic HTML". They probably meant basic HTML *syntax*, which is more encompassing. Also the fact that comments are listed there too. But that entire section is extremely arbitrary and lists some very puzzling examples. And that's why nobody here takes W3Schools seriously.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration

Comment: @BoltClock, Thank you for the response. One thing I have to say the way they categorized there - easy to remember for students what is the purpose of that group and where those tags can be used. But I think that is not official categorized, is that?

Comment: No, W3Schools is completely unofficial.

Answer (score 1):

W3Schools is not the official specification. It is just a site to help with code. The link you provided does not indicate that the doctype is a tag.

Doctype is not a tag. DOCTYPE is a required preamble.
It allows the browser to determine which version of html is being processed. This is obviously necessary to parse the following information correctly.

You should read w3 for a more informed understanding.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#the-doctype

It notes

> DOCTYPEs are required for legacy reasons. When omitted, browsers tend
> to use a different rendering mode that is incompatible with some
> specifications. Including the DOCTYPE in a document ensures that the
> browser makes a best-effort attempt at following the relevant
> specifications.

---

**Legacy**

For example HTML 4.01 used

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

HTML 5 dropped the declaration url meaning a document with no version statement is automatically parsed as html5.

e.g

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I know that. Came to be clear the way they added it to the list. For example - when I teach a student about html tags and say !DOCTYPE html is not a tag, they just show and say why it is there?

Comment: @Setu Quite simply, this is just bad organization on behalf of W3Schools which obviously causes confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, W3Schools isn't an authoritative source, and shouldn't be used in education. While it's true that its presence used to switch legacy browser behaviors, `<!DOCTYPE ...>` is from SGML on which HTML and XML is based. In SGML, `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM 'somefile.dtd>` is a *document type declaration* telling the parser the *document element* (that the root element is `html`) and where to find *markup declarations* for parsing, such as those telling SGML that HTML's `img` element doesn't have or need end-element tags.